# two-stage random experiment with poisson and binomal distribution

Tags: probability

given a two-stage random experiment with $X_{1}$ is Poisson(10) and if ${\{X_{1}=n}\}$, $X_{2}$ is $Bin(n;0.2)$ distributed.
I have to calculate the mean of $X_{2}$.

How do i calculate the probabilities without knowing the $n$?

*(The solution path is the following:
$\mathbb{E}[X_{2}]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X_{2}|X_{1}]]
 = \mathbb{E}[0.2\cdot X_{1}]= 0.2\cdot \mathbb{E}[X_{1}]= 0.2\cdot 10 = 2$)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We condition on the outcome of $X_1$.

Since $X_2|X_1=n \sim Bin(n,0.2), $ we have $E[X_2|X_1=n]=n(0.2)$.

hence

\begin{align}
E[X_2] &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty E[X_2|X_1=n]Pr(X_1=n)\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty n(0.2)Pr(X_1=n)\\
&=0.2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty nPr(X_1=n), \\
&= 0.2 E[X_1]
\end{align}

Comment: I see! I should consider rewriting the mean to solve such a problem!

Answer (score 0):

You have a statement "I have to calculate the mean of $X_2$." but the only question in your post is "How do i calculate the probabilities without knowing the $n$?"

The unconditional probability that $X_2=x_2$ is given by

$$Pr(X_2=x_2)=\sum _{n=x_2}^{\infty } \frac{\exp (-\lambda ) \lambda ^n p^{x_2} \binom{n}{x_2} (1-p)^{n-x_2}}{n!}=\frac{e^{-p\lambda} p^{x_2} \lambda ^{x_2}}{x_2!}$$

So from here just plug in $\lambda=10$ and $p=0.2$.